# Can we have a link back to the original question when improving an edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits, usability

I have started reviewing edits and find myself clicking on `improve` quite a lot.

Occasionally, an editor changes the the meaning of the original author, but once I am on the `improving` page, I can no longer see which parts have been edited.

To see that again, I have found that I can only do that by `cancelling` the edit, duplicate the window, and then start improving again. (Ctrl-clicking `back` will show a different suggested edit to review)

Another scenario is, that I need to go look at comments to check whether what has been edited in came from there, which is when I'm in need of a link back to the original question.

Here are some ideas:

- Add a link back to the original post
- Add a link to the diff between the suggested edit and the post
- Add a live diff between original/suggested/revised

What do you think?

Comment: Use your tabbed browsing. :)  It's a bit of a pain, but it works.

Answer (score 8):

## Screenshots:

Click the `Show diffs` heading to show and hide the diffs:

[image]

The diffs appear like this:

[image]

[image]

## Description:

Here's a short GreaseMonkey script that adds the diffs to the top of the improvement editor. I've never written an addon/extension but I bet this could be adapted into one.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        reviewhelp
// @namespace   http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/
// @include     *stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


$(document).on("click", '[value=Improve]', function() {
    if ($('.full-diff').length) {
        var table = $('<div/>').append($('.full-diff').clone()).hide();
        $('.editing-review-content').ajaxComplete(function() {
            $('#mainbar').prepend($("<hr/>"));
            $('#mainbar').prepend(table);
            var heading = $("<div><a href='#'><h2>Show diffs</h2></a></div>");
            $('#mainbar').prepend(heading);
            heading.toggle(function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
                $('h2', this).text('Hide diffs');
                $('a', this).css("color", "orange");
            }, function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
                $('h2', this).text('Show diffs');
                $('a', this).css("color", "");
            });
            heading.hover(function() {
                $('a', this).css("color", "orange")
            }, function() {
                if ($('h2', this).text() == 'Show diffs') $('a', this).css("color", "")
            });
        });
    }
});
```